# Can't get a simple angular-bootstrap example running on local machine

Tags: angularjs, local, angular-bootstrap

I'm not able to run a simple angular-bootstrap example. It runs well on Plunkr or on JSFiddle, but NOT locally on my machine. It's about a tab bar, so I use

```
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab>
       ...
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz95ccr7/) and this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXDutNqkQVJPI64WLP4x?p=preview) examples (both contain same code). They work like intended, showing me a tab bar with 3 tabs. Do I now put this code into a html file on my system and runs it locally, the following happens:

[image: result_in_firefox]

What is the reason behind this? The firefox console (F12) is empty, so there should be no error. Why can't I run my site locally? Do I need an extra server like tomcat for this? If yes, why? I just want to test something out real quick, I don't want to get a server only for this, except when it really is necessary...

PS: Note that these first steps actually worked!
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ But as soon as wanted to try out a tab bar, it keeps failing.

Comment: What does the example.html file contain?

Comment: It contains the exact same code as the jsfiddle and the plunker links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are referencing the external resources with **//** (*e.g. //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js*), you are not specifyng the protocol.

So when you access your file locally, it will keep the **file://** protocol (*e.g. file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js*) and this resources are obviously not available.

To solve the issue, you could use one of this methods:

- explicitly specify to use **http** (*e.g. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js*)
- save the external scripts on the directory with your html file and then use a relative path (e.g. angular.js)

Comment: I totally didn't see that ... why do they put such a referencing code into their examples? Damn :D Thank you very much, it works now.

Comment: @BAER because angular is used to create web apps, and web apps are typically served... over the web, by a web server. There are many things you can't do when the app is served from the file system: ajax calls, thus routing, etc. Assuming you're using a web server is reasaonable, IMO, because you should be using one.

Comment: I understand, you seem to be right. Thanks for clarification.